# how to prevent from force stop background android application by OS when system needs more resources for foreground applications?

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an internet calling app that uses firebase push notification to signal incoming calls, my problem is that if the app is not used for a few days and someone wants to call me, I don't get the push notification. After checking, I found that the operating system forcefully stopped my program.
How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: How is your app triggered?